# Evaluation of $\int_\Gamma e^{-z^2}\ dz$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

My question is simple. Prove the following equality

$$\int_\Gamma e^{-z^2}\ dz = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\ dx$$

where $\Gamma = \{ z\in {\bf \mathbb C}| \ {\rm Im}\ (z) = c \}$

Comment: It seems that your answer will be right. But the above statement is in 187p in Evans's book PDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider

$$\oint_C dz \, e^{-z^2}$$

where $C$ is a rectangle having vertices $-R$, $R$, $R+i c$, $-R+i c$.  By Cauchy's Theorem, this integral is zero.  On the other hand, it is also equal to

$$\int_{-R}^R dx \, e^{-x^2} + i \int_0^c dy \, e^{-(R+i y)^2} -\int_{\Gamma} dz \, e^{-z^2} -i \int_0^c dy \, e^{-(-R + i y)^2} $$

As $R\to\infty$, the 2nd and 4th integrals vanish because each integral is bounded by the value

$$e^{-R^2} \int_0^c dy \, e^{y^2} \le c e^{-(R^2-c^2)}$$

Thus, we are left with the equality

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, e^{-x^2} = \int_{\Gamma} dz \, e^{-z^2}$$

as was to be shown.